# Are biographies written as narratives in ancient world?

Tags: gospels

Matthew, Mark, Luke, John, and Acts are all written in a narrative style, but are treated as biographies of Jesus and his apostles.  Are there other examples in the ancient world of a biographical account of a real person being written in the 3rd person omniscient view like this?  That is, the author is intending to portray a biographical account, but writes in a 3rd person omniscient narrative style (typically indicative of fiction).